# Multiple recursion functions in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I need to recurse through two lists in a function and I can't see a way to do it.

```
siteRating6OrHigher :: [Film] -> [String]
siteRating6OrHigher [] = []
siteRating6OrHigher ((Film title _ _ ((_, rating):ratings)):restOfFilms)
    | rating >= 6 = [title] ++ siteRating6OrHigher restOfFilms
    | otherwise = siteRating6OrHigher restOfFilms
```

My data is formatted: `testDatabase = [Film "Blade Runner" "Ridley Scott" 1982 [("Amy",6), ("Bill",9), ("Ian",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Emma",4), ("Sam",5), ("Megan",4)],` etc

So  currently I am recursing through the '`restOfFilms`' but i also need to recurse through the list of ratings that are in the Film type. Is there a way to do this so it recurses through each set of ratings for each film?

Thanks

data structure:

```
data Film = Film String String Int [(String, Int)]
        deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Read)
```

Comment: Can you provide the data structures you're working with so the example is [self-contained](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Comment: What do you want to do with the ratings?

Comment: check if any rating in the list of ratings for a film is above six. My current method only checks the first one in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would fmap over the list, converting any ratings > 6 into boolean True, then use foldr to go through the list with `(||)` and default value False, which should reduce the list to a single True if any are above 6 and False otherwise.

```
foldr (||) False (fmap ((> 6) . snd) ratings)
```

*EDIT*: Simpler, as per Rhymoid's suggestion

*EDIT 2*: The whole solution.

```
siteRating6OrHigher :: [Film] -> [String]
siteRating6OrHigher [] = []
siteRating6OrHigher ((Film title _ _ ratings):restOfFilms)
    | above60 ratings = [title] ++ siteRating6OrHigher restOfFilms
    | otherwise = siteRating6OrHigher restOfFilms
  where above60 = any ((> 6) . snd)
```

Comment: Note that `any p = foldr (||) False . map p` is provided by the Prelude: you can just use `any (> 6)` instead.

Comment: That compiles fine but is still only returning the films that have a rating of greater than 6 in the first one, it doesnt seem to be recursing the other ones

Comment: is it possible to do the any .. as a list comprehension

Comment: @user3347868 You could do `any [r > 6 | (_, r) <- ratings]`, but I wouldn't say it's more readable than `any ((> 6) . snd)`

Comment: @bheklilr tried `siteRating6OrHigher :: [Film] -> [String]
siteRating6OrHigher [] = []
siteRating6OrHigher ((Film title _ _ ratings):restOfFilms)
    | (any [rating >= 6 | (_, rating) <- ratings ]) == True = [title] ++ siteRating6OrHigher restOfFilms
    | otherwise = siteRating6OrHigher restOfFilms` but it doesnt work

Comment: @user3347868 Sorry, I used the wrong function, should be `or` instead of `any`, I get those mixed up all the time.